# mysql query run slow

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this query

```
SELECT debtDinar,
       creditDinar,
       debtDollar,
       creditDollar AS creditDollar,
       companyID,
       costCenter,
       accountnumber,
       accountName,
       activityNo,
       activityName,
       name,
       if((debtDinar-creditDinar) >= 0.000,(debtDinar-creditDinar),0.000) AS debtDinarEx,
       if((debtDinar-creditDinar) >= 0.000,0.000,abs(debtDinar-creditDinar)) AS creditDinarEx,
       if((debtDollar-creditDollar) >= 0.00,(debtDollar-creditDollar),0.00) AS debtDollarEx,
       if((debtDollar-creditDollar) >= 0.00,0.00,abs(debtDollar-creditDollar)) AS creditDollarEx
FROM
  (SELECT SUM(recordsdetails.debtor) AS debtDinar,
          SUM(recordsdetails.creditor) AS creditDinar,
          SUM(recordsdetails.debtDollar) AS debtorDollar,
          SUM(recordsdetails.creditDollar) AS creditDollar,
          companies.name AS name,
          recordsdetails.companyID AS companyID,
          costCenter AS costCenter,
          accounts.accountnumber AS accountnumber,
          accounts.accountName AS accountName,
          recordsdetails.activityNo AS activityNo,
          recordsdetails.activityName AS activityName
   FROM (records,
         accounts
         JOIN (companies
               LEFT JOIN recordsdetails on((recordsdetails.companyID = companies.companyID))))
   WHERE left(recordsdetails.accountnumber,1)=accounts.accountnumber
     AND (recordsdetails.companyID = 1)
   GROUP BY accounts.accountnumber,
            costCenter
   ORDER BY accounts.sortorder) AS recordsdetails
```

it's run so slowly about 30-60 sec to get data and it's got more slow when data increase , is there any idea to make this query simple

Comment: show some dummy data .. what you want to achive

Comment: Indexes indexes indexes

Comment: Looks wrong: `WHERE left(recordsdetails.accountnumber,1)=accounts.accountnumber`

Comment: no,  it work ok but its so slowly  i think because i'am using `select from select`

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by neatening up your query. You have used mixed joining syntax, are missing aliases and renaming temp tables to the same name as a real table and as a result it is very hard to follow what is happening.

Are you actually using the table `records`? It appears to be cross joined in without any criteria..

You may be able to refactor out the `SELECT FROM (SELECT ... )` as well.

Once this is all neat and tidy, you should run an `EXPLAIN ...` and see which indexes are being used and where the query may be falling down.

Comment: this is all my criteria  ,`from (records,accounts join (companies left join recordsdetails      
                  on((recordsdetails.companyID = companies.companyID))))  
                  WHERE  left(recordsdetails.accountnumber,?)=accounts.accountnumber 
                  AND (recordsdetails.companyID =?) 
                  AND (recordsdetails.recordDate BETWEEN ? AND ?) 
                  AND (recordsdetails.accountNumber LIKE ? )
                  
           group by accounts.accountnumber,costCenter 
                  order by accounts.sortorder) AS recordsdetails`

Comment: @AlaaEssam I can see that, but what columns are you using from `records`? Is `costCenter` in that table?